# Node Webkit App and page displayed

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I am creating a desktop application with Node Webkit to create a file on disk.  It is working but when I try to send the succesful message to the page it reloads the page changing the title bar to index.html and deletes the heading it was before.  What I am doing wrong?

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
    <title>GPS API Client Builder</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var nw = require('nw.gui');

        //Window Menu
        var windowMenu = new nw.Menu({
            type: 'menubar'
        });
        //Help Menu
        var helpMenu = new nw.Menu();
        // Add to window menu
        windowMenu.append(new nw.MenuItem({
            label: 'Help',
            submenu: helpMenu
        }));
        //About sub entry
        helpMenu.append(new nw.MenuItem({
            label: 'About',
            click: function() {
                alert('I made this!');
            }

        }));
        //Assign window
        nw.Window.get().menu = windowMenu;
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>GUIApp!</h1>
    <!--<script src='script.js' type="text/javascript "></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript ">
        var os = require('os');
        var os = require('os');
        var fs = require('fs');
        var content = "";
        console.log('estoy en script file');
        content += 'This is a test of writing string to a text file' + os.EOL;
        content += 'This is a test of writing string to a text file' + os.EOL;
        content += 'This is a test of writing string to a text file' + os.EOL;
        content += 'This is a test of writing string to a text file' + os.EOL;
        console.log('content: ' + content);
        //write to file
        fs.writeFile('output.txt', content, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                document.write('Error writing file');
                //console.log('error writing');
            } else {
                document.write('file successfully created');
                // console.log('file successfully created');

            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the write() method nature.  It will overrite what was before.

[http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp][1]